# VS Code not showing changes and staged files showing as blank

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

At some point my VS Code started having an issue where viewing the changes shows the previous version as blank - like you would see if it were a new untracked file. This has always shown the correct information previously. If I run `git diff <filename>` then it shows the correct data, but VS Code shows it as:

[image: VS Code changes are blank for previous versions]

Along with that, when I stage the change(s) and then click on the file to view the changes, then nothing shows up on either pane:

[image: VS Code changes are blank for both the current and previous versions]

To the best of my knowledge I haven't changed a single thing (except some Windows updates) to my computer.

The only thing that I have done recently was to install Ruby and another Git addon for that, but this was much more recent than these problems.

I've tried:

- Disabling & reenabling the built-in Git extensions
- Opening files from both a mapped (S:) drive and the UNC path
- Disabling/removing/reinstalling all extensions
- Creating new files & directories
- Checking/unchecking diff & SCM settings
- Uninstalled & reinstalled VS Code and all other folders that don't get deleted after uninstallation per [How to uninstall VS Code completely](https://debug.to/1074/how-to-uninstall-vs-code-completely)

I don't have access to another repository otherwise I would try that next. I am utterly stumped and appreciate any help you might have. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I created a new local admin account on my computer with just my Microsoft login (as opposed to our domain credentials) and then cloned a repository from GitHub. It is showing all of the changes and behaving as expected. So I'm unsure if this is an issue with my user account now or with the repository. I'd appreciate any suggestions on what else I can try!

**Edit:** I have created a new repository locally, on a mapped network drive, and also via UNC directly and all of that works just fine (from my domain-logged-in account). It seems to be an issue with the repo directly at this point as far as I can tell.

Comment: Same issue here. Reverting back to vscode 1.63 and disabling vscode updates fixes the problem. Are your files located on a network drive? That seems to be a factor in this issue.

Comment: @harkov I created a new git repo on one of our network servers and it worked just fine using both a mapped drive letter and the UNC. But when I create new files in the exiting repository none of those changes show up.

Comment: I have the same problem regarding new files in the existing repo. However, opening the repo on the server itself in vscode works perfectly fine. So in my case it seems to be the combination of repository and opening it over a network. If I clone the repo locally, the changes show up as well. I've run git gc and fsck but the git can't find a problem with the repo.

Comment: @LoViSobreTusHombros : do you confirm your issue is linked to accessing the repo over a network ? have you had time to try to try vscode 1.63 as harkov suggested ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed with VSCode 1.70 (July 2022), and [issue 142842](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142842), fixed by [PR 154342](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154342).

```js
// On Windows, there are cases in which the normalized path for a mapped folder contains a trailing `\`
// character (ex: \\server\folder\) due to the implementation of `path.normalize()`. This behaviour is
// by design as documented in https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1765.
```

The fix references "[Windows: `fs.realpathSync()` adds trailing slash for windows share](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1765)".

This is released in [VSCode insider today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Comment: This update did indeed fix the issue that I've been having. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this - there appears to be 2 source control menus when you right click in VS Code. I deselected the one with the shortcut and selected the one without the shortcut and now the required menu is back!

[image]

Comment: That looks weird. Do you have any extensions installed that might add that second item?